# How to prove isomorphism maintains dimension of kernel space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and let $P: V \rightarrow V$ and $Q: W \rightarrow W$ be isomorphisms (my textbook defines this as the linear mappings are injective and surjective). It is required to prove that:

- $dim(Ker(T)) = dim(Ker(QTP))$
- $dim(Im(T)) = dim(Im(QTP))$

I understand intuitively why this may be true. Since $P$ is surjective, we have a mapping to every vector from the domain to the co-domain, thus we have not made the "pre-image" of $T$ any smaller. Also, $Q$ is surjective, so we are also not shortening any of the outputs from $T$. Intuitively, since we do not "siphon" off any of the inputs and outputs of $T$, the solutions for the $Ker(T)$ remain of the same cardinality and can still be reached. A similar argument can be used for the second proof question. However, I don't think this is rigorous at all, but I'm not sure how at all to tackle this question. Any hints or insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: isomorphisms send bases to bases. Therefore let $B$ be a basis of $\ker T$ and let $C$ be a basis of $\operatorname{im} T$. Since every element in $P^{-1}(B)$ belongs to $\ker QTP$, $P^{-1}(B)$ is a basis of $\ker QTP$. And since every element in $Q(C)$ belongs to $\operatorname{im} QTP$, $Q(C)$ is a basis of $\operatorname{im} QTP$.

To be a bit more rigorous: $$\begin{align}v \in \ker QTP &\iff QTP(v) = 0 \\ &\iff TP(v) = 0 \\ &\iff P(v) \in \ker T = \operatorname{span}B \\ &\iff v \in \operatorname{span} P^{-1}(B).\end{align}$$

And similarly for the image.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is bijective (1-1 and onto) then $P$ is invertable.

$x$ is in the kernel of T then $P^{-1} x$ is in the kernel of $TP$.
And, if $x$ is not in the kernel of $T$,$P^{-1} x$ is not in the kernel of $TP$.

And Q is 1-1.

If $TP = 0$ then $QTP = 0$.
And, if $TP$ is not $0$, $QTP$ is not $0$